# SQL: Is there a data type for just *letters* only?

Tags: mysql, sql, types, sqldatatypes

I need a data type for letters only so then i could test for Erroneous please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

**No.**

Long answer:

This kind of validation logic is best done in your application layer. The database should be responsible for persisting data and validating relationships, nothing more. If you have a validation requirement, chances are it's non-trivial, so you'll need a more expressive language to define it than MySQL stored procedures and triggers can provide.